# React / CSS - float nav bar right with flex boxes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

This is probably a relatively simple CSS situation but now working in React and also trying to display an `Image` component inline in the nav things are getting difficult -

I have an animated nav I took and tweaked from https://codepen.io/littlesnippets/pen/OyxyRG and I need to float it right. I want to display my Image inline at the same horizontal position as the nav items and float it left so the whole nav looks like:

[image]

Here's what I have, which aligns everything to center:

```
<main className={styles.main}>

        <div className={styles.nav}>
          <Image className={styles.navIcon} src={icon} width={40} height={40} />
          <ul className={styles.snip1168}>
            <li className={styles.current}><a href="#" data-hover="Work">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-hover="Recs">Recs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-hover="Say Hi">Say Hi</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 4rem 0;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Start custom nav */

.nav {
  margin-top: 2.4em; /* coordinates w height of line away from link, MUST BE = */
}

.snip1168 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.snip1168 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.snip1168 li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
}
.snip1168 a {
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  padding-top: 2.4em; /* height of line away from link */
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.snip1168 a:before,
.snip1168 a:after {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}
.snip1168 a:before {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0%;
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
}

.snip1168 a:hover:before,
.snip1168 .current a:before {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
.snip1168 a:hover:after,
.snip1168 .current a:after {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

I've tried `float` properties as well as `justify-content` options. How can I create this alignment?

```css
.container {
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 4rem 0;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "sequel-sans-roman", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}
.navIcon {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.nav {
  margin-top: 2.4em; /* coordinates w height of line away from link, MUST BE = */
}

.snip1168 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.snip1168 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.snip1168 li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
}
.snip1168 a {
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  padding-top: 2.4em; /* height of line away from link */
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.snip1168 a:before,
.snip1168 a:after {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}
.snip1168 a:before {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0%;
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
}

.snip1168 a:hover:before,
.snip1168 .current a:before {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
.snip1168 a:hover:after,
.snip1168 .current a:after {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.mainText {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div className={styles.container}>
<main className={styles.main}>

        <div className={styles.nav}>
          <div className={styles.navIcon}>
            <Image src={icon} height={40} width={40} />
          </div>
          <ul className={styles.snip1168}>
            <li className={styles.current}><a href="#" data-hover="Work">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-hover="Recs">Recs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-hover="Say Hi">Say Hi</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The easiest way is to put a `flexGrow: 1` on the left element to make it take up any remaining space.

Comment: Did that, didnt do much

Comment: Add the code in a snippet and I'll get it working for you.

Comment: @JoelHager Just saved to snippet. It doesnt look like it does on my side so the Codepen might be a better bet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution is to set

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2.4em;
  /* coordinates w height of line away from link, MUST BE = */
}
```

Here is a full snippet

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "sequel-sans-roman", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 4rem 0;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navIcon {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2.4em;
  /* coordinates w height of line away from link, MUST BE = */
}

.snip1168 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.snip1168 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.snip1168 li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
}

.snip1168 a {
  padding: 2.4em 0 0.5em;
  /* height of line away from link */
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.snip1168 a:before,
.snip1168 a:after {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

.snip1168 a:before {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0%;
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
}

.snip1168 a:hover:before,
.snip1168 .current a:before {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.snip1168 a:hover:after,
.snip1168 .current a:after {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.mainText {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <main class='main'>
    <div class='nav'>
      <div class='navIcon'>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/40" height={40} width={40} />
      </div>
      <ul class='snip1168'>
        <li class='current'><a href="#" data-hover="Work">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-hover="Recs">Recs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-hover="Say Hi">Say Hi</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing! How would I move the nav to the top of the screen? Not stuck there, but positioned near

Comment: you need to remove this `min-height: 100vh;` from `.main` if is still a lot spacing it is because of the `padding: 4rem 0;`

Comment: Amazing. Apologies for continuing - now the content below the nav, which needs to stay centered on the page, is also pushed to the top. Is there a way to easily center this vertically?

Answer (score 0):

Here I add some borders just to show where things are. I removed CSS not relevant to the question and showed a rendered HTML set to better illustrate.

```css
.container {
  padding: 0 2rem;
  border: solid 1px pink;
}

.main {
  border: 1px solid green;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  border: solid blue 1px;
}

.navIcon {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.navIcon img {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

ul.snip1168 {
  width: 30%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <main class='main'>
    <div class='nav'>
      <div class='navIcon'>
        <img src="icon" alt="myicon" />
      </div>
      <ul class='snip1168'>
        <li class='current'><a href="#" data-hover="Work">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-hover="Recs">Recs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-hover="Say Hi">Say Hi</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```